# RecurringJob with multiple Queue and multiple server

Tags: hangfire

I have multiple projects that run RecurringJob and do not share any assembly, so every job assembly exists in its project and not others. I configured every project with a unique queue in Hangfire and register my jobs with that queue. But in the run time, server1 run try to run a job that exists in another server.
This is my sample code for Machine 3

```
var job3 = new Job3();
var options = new RecurringJobOptions()
{
    QueueName = "machine3"
};
_recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("Job3",queue: "machine3", () =>job3.Run(), "0 * * * * *",options );
```

This is my sample code for Machine 2

```
var options = new RecurringJobOptions()
{
      QueueName = "machine2"
};
var job2 = new Job2();
_recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("Job2", queue: "machine2", () => job2.Run(), "20 * * * * *", options);
```

Now, I wonder how should I do that.
I read the source code and found that every server can change the state to schedule an for that need the source code